# Не пойму, почему выражение не работает при больших значениях (a / 2) * (a - 1)

Tags: python

У меня есть простой алгоритм:

```
a = int(input())
b = int((a / 2) * (a - 1))
print (b)
```

Я не пойму, почему при больших значениях вывод искажается.

Например, при вводе `1000000000000` следует вывод `49999999999950003057459`,
а должно быть `499999999999500000000000`.

Python 3.8

Comment: *при вводе 1000000000000 следует вывод 49999999999950003057459* https://pyfiddle.io так не считает...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перепишите ваш  код в целочисленное деление:

```
a = int(input())
b = a * (a - 1) // 2
print (b)
```

и всё заработает.
В Python 3+ `a/2` дает результат `float`.
Дело в том, что a * (a - 1) всегда четное, а вам нужно целое значение.
Для этого вам нужно немного изменить порядок операций как я указал.

Answer (score 3):

Потому, что полученное в результате деления [число с плавающей запятой](https://habr.com/ru/post/112953/) не может точно представить результат этого деления. А согласно [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

> Division of integers yields a float, while floor division of integers
>   results in an integer; the result is that of mathematical division
>   with the ‘floor’ function applied to the result.

Результатом деление целых чисел будет число с плавающей точкой. А результатом делении целых чисел оператором `//` будет целое число. Но если один из операндов - число с плавающей точкой, то результатом будет число с плавающей точкой. Например:

```
a = int('1000000000000') # int(input())
b = (a // 2) * (a - 1)
print (b, type(b), sep='\n')
c = (a / 2) * (a - 1)
print(c, type(c), int(c), sep='\n')
d = (a // 2.0) * (a - 1)
print(d, type(d), int(d), sep='\n')
```

Вывод:

```
499999999999500000000000
<class 'int'>
4.999999999995e+23
<class 'float'>
499999999999500030574592
4.999999999995e+23
<class 'float'>
499999999999500030574592
```

Далее - попытка показать, что происходит:

```
import struct
a = 1000000000000
f = (a / 2) * (a - 1)
d = struct.pack('d', f)
Q = struct.unpack('Q', d)[0]
bs = format(Q, '064b')
print(bs)
sign = bs[0]
print('Знак:', sign)
exponent = int(bs[1:12], 2) - 1023
print('Порядок:', exponent, '')
fraction = bs[12:]
print('Мантисса:', fraction)
r = 2**exponent + sum(int(b) * 2**(exponent - i - 1) for i, b in enumerate(fraction))
print(r)
```

Для получения двоичного представления числа с плавающей запятой используется модуль [struct](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/struct.html). Число с плавающей точкой упаковывается функцией [struct.pack](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/struct.html#struct.pack). Результат функцией [struct.unpack](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) распаковывается как `unsigned long long`, а встроенная функция [format](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#format) возвращает его строковое двоичное представление длинной в 64 `0/1`. Затем это представление преобразуется в число в соответствии с приведенной выше статьей.
Результатом работы скрипта будет:

```
0100010011011010011110000100001101111001110110011000000010011010
Знак: 0
Порядок: 78 
Мантисса: 1010011110000100001101111001110110011000000010011010
499999999999500030574592
```